# Connecting to Postgres in Docker using Dbeaver on Windows

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, localhost, dbeaver

Docker is working on WSL with Ubuntu distrubutive. I am just starting to try working with databases and have encountered some difficulties. The problem is that I can't connect to the Docker database using Dbeaver or pgadmin.

`docker-compose` file:

[image]

After `docker-compose up` I got 2 containers. First is my database, second is admin. From "Inspect" file of "pagila" container I've got IPaddress and tried to connect to it in Dbeaver using this IPaddress.

[image]
But in result I got "time limit exceeded".

From `netstat -ano` I got this port is "Listening" on localhost.
[image]
From task manager for PID I got this
[image]
I can connect to this contaier from command line using `docker exec -it pagila psql -U postgres`. It is successful.

Maybe I shuld connect on the `0.0.0.0` host? But there is other issue:

[image]

I tried different variations of the connection, but none of them worked. Can someone help me? Maybe there's something I don't understand.

If I try to connect on localhost, it will be a local server. But i want to get db from docker...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: I don't think that's a dupe @richyen; he's trying to connect to the exposed port on 6543.  I am guessing 172.23.0.3 is postgresql's docker-side network address?  If that will work, you'll want to use the port _inside_ docker, 5432, not the one being forwarded to it.   `0.0.0.0` isn't really a valid destination IP, but it generally works in linux; that might not be the case in windows.  Try 127.0.0.1?

Comment: I could've sworn I answered an issue like this one before :( but yeah try `host=127.0.0.1` and `port=6543`

Comment: @richyen Yes! It is working now, but here's the weird thing. This sample database is taken from [pagila](https://github.com/devrimgunduz/pagila) and originally had a user password of 123456. and the problem was that I changed it. No other password can be used to connect to it. Is there potentially a password verification/validation somewhere?

Comment: @richyen I have connected on `host=localhost` or `host=127.0.0.1` and `port=6543`. But I really don't know what was the problem with the password.
Thanks for the thoughts to think about @erik258

Answer (score 0):

When working with Docker containers, and especially with `docker-compose`, it is important to bear in mind that `docker-compose` sets up a virtual network that allows the containers to talk to each other via the same subnet (`172.23.0.*` in your case).  This subnet is not accessible by the host machine.  Instead, by exposing ports and mapping ports (`6543:5432` in your case), Docker allows access to containers/services within that virtual network.

Therefore to use DBeaver to connect to the database, you need to use the `localhost` hostname or loopback IP (`127.0.0.1`), and access the exposed port (`6543`).  So in DBeaver, you'll want to use `host=localhost` and `port=6543`

Regarding your passwords, since you defined `POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1313` in your `docker-compose.yml` file, you should be able to use `1313` to access the database from DBeaver.  However, bear in mind that this password is set at the `initdb` stage (when the container is created).  If your `1-pagila-schema.sql` file contains some kind of `ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD ...` statement, you'll override the `1313` password.

Another possibility with the password is that since you are calling with `pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data`, there may be a pre-existing database with a pre-defined password.  I'm not 100% sure, but if there's a pre-existing database, `initdb` won't be called, and therefore the password won't get set to `1313`, so adjust accordingly.

Comment: I think it is not a pre-existinig database and not a predefined password, since I changed the password without clearing anything (maybe docker-compose down deletes the pre-existing database?). I haven't found anything similar in the initialization scripts for setting a password for a user so far. Thanks for the help!